# Network Latency from Azure cloud to Mainframe

Tags: java, azure, migration, mainframe, latency

I am working on a mainframe migration project where code is migrated to Java and on Azure cloud but DB2 database is still in mainframe. I am completely new to cloud world so don't know about the services and tools.
Is there a way to measure network latency from cloud to mainframe during DB2 calls? We need how much time it actually takes going from cloud to mainframe, executing the statement (anything to find this specifically?) and then return to cloud. Time spent on cloud and on mainframe, to be specific. Could you please suggest any tool, pre-installed services or method to do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Mainframe Performance expert here. (Look me up if you doubt that.)

For Db2 on z/OS there is excellent instrumentation. In particular there is Db2 Accounting Trace - for individual connections to Db2. But...

... To use it you really are going to need to talk to your Db2-on-z/OS administrators. I would hope they would help you in your quest.

Assuming this is strategic to your / their organisation, they can always come and talk to me - martin_packer@uk.ibm.com - and I have some Open Source tooling that would probably be useful to them (but probably not to you).